# Postgres Multiple Version Installion

Tags: postgresql

I am working with postgres. Straight to the point...

When I run postgres and check the version with `SELECT version();` it shows "11.5".

But when I check it using `pg_config --version` it shows "PostgreSQL 10.10".

I think I have installed two versions. How can I retain one?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have two versions.

I don't know what distro you are using, but in Fedora/RHEL/Centos, the pg_config binary comes from the libpq-devel and postgresql-upgrade-devel packages whereas the postgres binary comes from the postgresql-server and postgresql-upgrade packages.

To sum it up, they are two different binaries for two different packages. You won't have two versions of Postgresql Server installed unless you actively do so.

Answer (score 0):

check this directory and see if you installed multiple versions
`/usr/lib/systemd/system/` find postgresql*.service and if it is multiple you installed multiple of them.